# Composite Foreign Key Constraint Not Enforced When NULL Allowed, Any Solution?

Tags: mysql, triggers, foreign-keys

I'm using mysql 5.6.20 and I have following schema:

Project Activity Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `prj_project_activity_detail` (
    `fkPrjProjectActivity` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `fkPrjProjectActivitySub` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `fkProjectId` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`fkPrjProjectActivity`, `fkPrjProjectActivitySub`, `fkProjectId`),
    INDEX `FK__prj_project_activity` (`fkPrjProjectActivity`, `fkProjectId`),
    INDEX `FK__prj_project_activity_2` (`fkPrjProjectActivitySub`, `fkProjectId`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK__prj_project_activity` FOREIGN KEY (`fkPrjProjectActivity`, `fkProjectId`) REFERENCES `prj_project_activity` (`PrjProjectActivity`, `fkProjectId`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK__prj_project_activity_2` FOREIGN KEY (`fkPrjProjectActivitySub`, `fkProjectId`) REFERENCES `prj_project_activity` (`PrjProjectActivity`, `fkProjectId`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Data:

```
fkPrjProjectActivity    fkPrjProjectActivitySub     fkProjectId
Activity 1                  Sub Activity 1              1
Activity 1                  Sub Activity 2              1
Activity 1                  Sub Activity 3              1
```

Transaction Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `str_transaction` (
    `StrTransactionId` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    `fkPrjProjectActivity` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `fkPrjProjectActivitySub` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `fkProjectId` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`StrTransactionId`),
    INDEX `FK_str_transaction_department` (`fkTransactionForStoreDepartmentId`),
    INDEX `FK_str_transaction_prj_project_activity_detail` (`fkPrjProjectActivity`, `fkPrjProjectActivitySub`, `fkProjectId`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_str_transaction_prj_project_activity_detail` FOREIGN KEY (`fkPrjProjectActivity`, `fkPrjProjectActivitySub`, `fkProjectId`) REFERENCES `prj_project_activity_detail` (`fkPrjProjectActivity`, `fkPrjProjectActivitySub`, `fkProjectId`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Expected Enforce Data:

```
StrTransactionId    fkPrjProjectActivity    fkPrjProjectActivitySub     fkProjectId
1                       Activity 1                  Sub Activity 2          1
2                       Activity 1                  Sub Activity 3          1
```

But it allows me to insert any data as shown below:

Unexpected Result:

```
StrTransactionId    fkPrjProjectActivity    fkPrjProjectActivitySub     fkProjectId
1                       Dummy 1                 Sub Activity 2              (NULL)
2                       Activity 1              (NULL)                      1
3                       Dummy 1                 Dummy 1                     (NULL)
```

The weird thing is, it even accepts the data which are not in parent table.

IS FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT ENFORCES ONLY WHEN ALL COLUMNS CONTAIN DATA?

I want to enforce constraint if any of the column contains data or all columns must be NULL.

Mysql Doc. says, [(link)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.7/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html)

> The MATCH clause in the SQL standard controls how NULL values in a
>   composite (multiple-column) foreign key are handled when comparing to
>   a primary key. MySQL essentially implements the semantics defined by
>   MATCH SIMPLE, which permit a foreign key to be all or partially NULL.
>   In that case, the (child table) row containing such a foreign key is
>   permitted to be inserted, and does not match any row in the referenced
>   (parent) table. It is possible to implement other semantics using
>   triggers.

I cannot make "NOT NULL" as it is basic requirement. I have many other fields in `str_transaction` table which (irrelevant to question) are removed here for better clarity of the question.

Is it good practice to implement trigger as suggested in the doc? Or can anyone help me to design the architecture?

Comment: Why not use a synthetic PK in `prj_project_activity_detail` instead of your composite natural one?

Answer (score 0):

Like eggyal suggested, i would create an autoincrement primary key for `prj_project_activity_detail` table and a foreign key for `str_transaction` table that references it.

The structure could look like that:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `prj_project_activity_detail` (
    `prjProjectActivityDetailId` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fkPrjProjectActivity` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `fkPrjProjectActivitySub` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `fkProjectId` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`prjProjectActivityDetailId`),
    INDEX `FK__prj_project_activity` (`fkPrjProjectActivity`, `fkProjectId`),
    INDEX `FK__prj_project_activity_2` (`fkPrjProjectActivitySub`, `fkProjectId`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK__prj_project_activity` FOREIGN KEY (`fkPrjProjectActivity`, `fkProjectId`) REFERENCES `prj_project_activity` (`PrjProjectActivity`, `fkProjectId`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK__prj_project_activity_2` FOREIGN KEY (`fkPrjProjectActivitySub`, `fkProjectId`) REFERENCES `prj_project_activity` (`PrjProjectActivity`, `fkProjectId`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `str_transaction` (
    `StrTransactionId` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    `fkPrjProjectActivityDetailId` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`StrTransactionId`),
    INDEX `FK_str_transaction_prj_project_activity_detail` (`fkPrjProjectActivityDetailId`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_str_transaction_prj_project_activity_detail` FOREIGN KEY (`fkPrjProjectActivityDetailId`) REFERENCES `prj_project_activity_detail` (`prjProjectActivityDetailId`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now you will not be able to insert invalid data like in your example, because your foregn key is either an existing `prjProjectActivityDetailId` or `NULL`.

To simulate your old `str_transaction` table you can create a view with a left join:

```sql
CREATE VIEW `str_transaction_view` AS
    SELECT 
      st.StrTransactionId,
      pad.fkPrjProjectActivity,
      pad.fkPrjProjectActivitySub,
      pad.fkProjectId
    FROM str_transaction st
    LEFT JOIN prj_project_activity_detail pad
      ON pad.prjProjectActivityDetailId = st.fkPrjProjectActivityDetailId;
```

[Sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b6aee/1)